# Create channel on peer fails

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The official hyperledger fabric v1.0.0 gives a simple demo by using docker. Here is the link.

What i am doing is to avoid docker and directly run them on the machine. Thanks to the answer from my previous question, I have successfully launch 1 solo orderer and two peers, each from one org.

This is part of orderer's config orderer.yaml and i am sure the tls-related path is set correctly.

```
General:

    # Ledger Type: The ledger type to provide to the orderer.
    # Two non-production ledger types are provided for test purposes only:
    #  - ram: An in-memory ledger whose contents are lost on restart.
    #  - json: A simple file ledger that writes blocks to disk in JSON format.
    # Only one production ledger type is provided:
    #  - file: A production file-based ledger.
    LedgerType: file

    # Listen address: The IP on which to bind to listen.
    ListenAddress: 127.0.0.1

    # Listen port: The port on which to bind to listen.
    ListenPort: 7040

    # TLS: TLS settings for the GRPC server.
    TLS:
        Enabled: true
        PrivateKey: ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.key
        Certificate: ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        RootCAs:
          - ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt
        ClientAuthEnabled: false
        ClientRootCAs:

    # Log Level: The level at which to log. This accepts logging specifications
    # per: fabric/docs/Setup/logging-control.md
    LogLevel: debug
```

However, when I want to create the channel using command as follows:

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
export CHANNEL_NAME=my_channel
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"

export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7001

peer channel create -o 127.0.0.1:7040 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt
```

The log reports the error saying as follows:

```
Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"
```

I think it is related to a tls configuration problem. I am not very familiar about it. Can any one help me to solve this simple problem and give me a simple explanation?

Comment: You might be interested to know that IP-based SANs have been introduced in the upcoming version (v1.1)! See: <https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-4364>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused due to hostname verification failing at the TLS layer.
The TLS certificates don't have IP Subject Alternative Names (SANs) - they only have DNS-based SANs.

The easiest thing to do is to just add host entries into your **/etc/hosts** file (assuming you are running on Linux or macOS).  Assuming that you are running everything on the same machine, then adding the following line to your **/etc/hosts** should resolve your issue:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost orderer peer0.org1.example.com peer0.org2.example.com
```

And then make sure to use the hostnames rather than IP addresses:

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
export CHANNEL_NAME=my_channel
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"

export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7001

peer channel create -o orderer:7040 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt
```